# Laravel: moving project to production

Tags: php, laravel

I've heard that there's a way to [install laravel without using composer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15940355/978953). So I'm trying to push my development laravel project to production server, but i have this error:

> Error in exception handler: include() [function.include]: Unable to
>   allocate memory for pool. in
>   .../vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:363

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should read this first: http://laravel.com/docs/installation#install-laravel

Answer (score 3):

This is probably related to [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58982).

You should check your `ini` settings for php. Try to look for the settings of `apc.mmap_file_mask`. You might want to try to tweak that.

Also you can find more information at the php docs.

> apc.mmap_file_mask string If compiled with MMAP support by using
>   --enable-mmap this is the mktemp-style file_mask to pass to the mmap module for determining whether your mmap'ed memory region is going to
>   be file-backed or shared memory backed. For straight file-backed mmap,
>   set it to something like /tmp/apc.XXXXXX (exactly 6 Xs). To use
>   POSIX-style shm_open/mmap put a .shm somewhere in your mask. e.g.
>   /apc.shm.XXXXXX You can also set it to /dev/zero to use your kernel's
>   /dev/zero interface to anonymous mmap'ed memory. Leaving it undefined
>   will force an anonymous mmap.

Try something like:

```
//mmap directly from /dev/zero, use:
apc.mmap_file_mask=/dev/zero
```

Or maybe update your version of PHP to latest? That would maybe help, though I don't have any more information on that. But I believe that this is related to that report.

---

Also please do read the docs on laravel, specially this: [Install Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#install-laravel).

Do this for the first method (non composer install):

```
curl -sS http://laravel.com/laravel.phar | php
$ (sudo) mv laravel.phar /usr/local/bin/laravel
```

---

As for moving to production, just move your files without the vendor directory. On the production server execute the composer install again which will install all dependencies and should have you a production ready server running.