# What are some reasons why Composer will fail to connect to packagist through http, if not behind a firewall or proxy?

Tags: composer-php, centos5, packagist

I have been trying to use Composer on Centos 5.5. I managed to install it, but  `composer install` gets me nowhere, yielding:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                             
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

Similarly, `composer diag` displays the following:

```
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: FAIL

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "//packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out

Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version:
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                         
  The "//getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

I've done searches on this error and have turned up discussions of how to get around a proxy. But according to the sysadmin, my IP has complete access, with no firewall or proxy blocking me.

How do I begin to troubleshoot this?

*edit to add traceroute results per Sven's suggestion*

```
traceroute to packagist.org (87.98.253.214), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets

1  a9.39.5646.static.theplanet.com (70.86.57.169)  1.258 ms  1.532 ms  1.760 ms
2  po202.dsr01.dllstx2.networklayer.com (70.87.254.145)  0.540 ms  0.579 ms  0.689 ms
3  po21.dsr01.dllstx3.networklayer.com (70.87.255.65)  0.574 ms  0.676 ms  0.796 ms
4  ae17.bbr02.eq01.dal03.networklayer.com (173.192.18.230)  0.406 ms  0.410 ms  0.404 ms
5  * eqx.dal.ovh.net (206.223.118.119)  0.508 ms ae7.bbr01.eq01.dal03.networklayer.com (173.192.18.208)  0.401 ms
6  * dal-1-6k.tx.us (178.32.135.174)  0.559 ms *
7  nwk-1-6k.nj.us (178.32.135.222)  38.725 ms * *
8  nwk-1-6k.nj.us (178.32.135.222)  38.690 ms  38.680 ms  38.773 ms
9  * gra-g1-a9.fr.eu (37.187.36.211)  115.493 ms *
10  gra-3a-a9.fr.eu (37.187.231.86)  113.173 ms gra-g1-a9.fr.eu (37.187.36.211)  113.189 ms  113.294 ms
11  gra-3a-a9.fr.eu (37.187.231.86)  113.022 ms  111.916 ms *
12  * * *
13  * * *
etc until
30  * * *
```

Comment: More clues:  I can ping and wget www.google.com fine.  I can't ping or wget packagist.org successfully. 
`nmap -P0 -p 443 packagist.org` yields

>Starting Nmap 4.11 ( http://www.insecure.org/nmap/ ) at 2015-05-21 15:20 CDT
Interesting ports on packagist.org (87.98.253.214):
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
443/tcp filtered https

>Nmap finished: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 12.226 seconds

Comment: Perhaps a traceroute to the host would reveal some blocking system. Just now I was able to use my browser to get to Packagist, so the site is up and running. Or maybe your IP is blocked on the remote host.

Comment: @Sven Packagist doesn't block and/or filter. [ref](https://github.com/composer/packagist/issues/466#issuecomment-67321611)

Comment: @AlexandruGuzinschi Your reference tells that Packagist itself doesn't block, but it might be that the hosting provider does. Traceroute to the target would probably give more ideas where to look.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!  Traceroute results are following, but I'm still looking up how to interpret them. :P

Comment: I've done a number of traceroutes and it seems that they are always pooping out at the 10th or 11th hop at gra-3a-a9.fr.eu (37.187.231.86).  Does this mean that we are being blocked? I'm using a shared host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that Sven (in comments: Sven, if you will post as an answer I will accept it) had the best answer so far: traceroute shows we are being blocked en route by gra-3a-a9.fr.eu. I don't know what to do about that, so I gave up trying to use composer on the server. Instead, I'm trying to work around it by installing composer on localhost, and was able to connect to packagist just fine. I then uploaded everything to the server, now including the "vendor" directory created by Composer.

Some more discussion on how to install without composer locally... the techniques listed here are specific to Laravel but I found it worked fine for other packages.
http://jafty.com/blog/installing-laravel-without-composer/

[Can I Install Laravel without using Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940140/can-i-install-laravel-without-using-composer)

Thanks all for your suggestions!