# Laravel 5.1 Composer.json Call File in Autoload

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I just want to create a global function in laravel 5.1
I create a file in App/Helper.php

Helper.php

```
 <?php 
    namespace App\Helpers;
    class Helpers {
        public function somethingOrOther()
        {
            return "Yes It is";
        }
}
```

test.blade.php

```
Helpers::somethingOrOther();
```

But it is not working

Every Time I gon a fatel error like "Class 'App\Helpers' not found"

Please Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are Helper method are statics you could add your helper class your config/app alias just like a Facade, like so:

```
'aliases' => [
    //'Helpers'=> 'App\Helpers\Helpers', //for Laravel 5.0
    'Helpers'=> App\Helpers\Helpers::class, //for Laravel 5.1
]
```

check this question

[What is the best practice to create a custom helper function in php Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804201/what-is-the-best-practice-to-create-a-custom-helper-function-in-php-laravel-5)

Comment: It's Done..Thank You again

Comment: And How can i access my model in this file....? When  i try to access i got an error.....So i need to do anything special

Comment: @KevalGarala. i didn't got what you said .can you elobarate ?

Comment: I want to use my model in function                                                     public static function getCmsBlocks($id)
{
$model = Modelname::all();
return $cmsblock
}

Comment: oops.i think its difficult use model in your helper class.(but i am not sure as per my knowledge)you can create static class inside model

Comment: can you provide me your mail id...?