# Localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 with laravel app in Win 10

Tags: php, laravel

I have imported Laravel app inside my PC (Win 10) and put it in htdocs folder then I have changed the default directory which will serve me when type "localhost" in the browser to be Laravel app directory by did these changes in httpd.conf xampp file like that

```
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/zaad/public"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/zaad/public">
```

But when go to the browser and type localhost it gets me this error "Localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500"
[image]

The problem doesn't get from xampp or Apache serve because other apps inside htdocs work as they are expected, so I guess the problem from windows permission or some thing related to that.

Comment: Did you run composer install? `php artisan key:generate`? properly set `env` values? Check the laravel log file for error info.

Comment: Why not using artisan serve, make sure you did setup `.env` and run composer install before running the project, also check using `localhost/index.php`

Comment: My co-worker did as i did and it's work from his side but he has Mac not Windows, therefore i expect the error from Win permissions
in addition i don't want to install composer then laravel and all these staff @iamab.in

Comment: Do you have the `vendor` folder in your project? If not you have to copy those too. I suggest using composer to develop/run a laravel project on a local server. check [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940140/can-i-install-laravel-without-using-composer)

Comment: Can you check is there any issues logged in the log file located in `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: It's same when going to localhost/index.php @HassanRaza

Comment: logs folder doesn't exist inside storage at all
vendor folder exists
@iamab.in

Comment: Check your xampp php version and project version

Comment: Xampp Version: 3.2.4,
php version inside Xampp: 7.2.28,
php version inside app: ^7.3|^8.0
@HassanRaza

Comment: Try using xampp with php version greater than 7.3